# isw_raid_member (Intel Rapid Storage) on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, raid

I have 3 HDD's configured as an Intel Rapid Storage RAID5, configured by my desktop's motherboard (Asus P8Z77-V LX) integrated firmware via BIOS. The RAID is then formatted with an NTFS partition.

In autumn I moved the drives to a headless Debian 8 home server, running mdadm 3.2. It was able to automatically recognize and create a device for the RAID without issue.

However, I can't get any more recent version of mdadm (3.3+) to recognize the RAID. I eventually tried erasing the superblocks and recreating a Linux RAID5, but that lead to a completely broken filesystem, to the point that even raw data recovery only found broken files (an issue might be that Intel Rapid Storage computes stripe chunk sizes in KIBIbytes, whereas mdadm only creates stripes with chunks in KILObytes).

I have since recovered the data by moving the disks back to my desktop and recreating an Intel RAID on top of them, as originally was.

I would however like to use updated versions of mdadm and not just pin it to 3.2, if anything because they're required to upgrade to Debian 9. Does anybody know how to go about it?

The following is from my desktop system, Arch, running mdadm 4.0 and with BIOS RAID support disabled, so it just sees the physical drives. RAID devices are sdc, sdd, sde, as you can see.

```
[root@desktop-linux fabrizio]# lsblk -o +FSTYPE
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT          FSTYPE          
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk                                                  
164375471010
└─sda1   8:1    0 111,8G  0 part /                    ext4            
sdb      8:16   0 119,2G  0 disk                                      
├─sdb1   8:17   0   500M  0 part                      ntfs            
└─sdb2   8:18   0 118,8G  0 part /mnt/win10_os        ntfs            
sdc      8:32   0   1,8T  0 disk                      isw_raid_member 
sdd      8:48   0   1,8T  0 disk                      isw_raid_member 
sde      8:64   0   1,8T  0 disk                      isw_raid_member 
sdf      8:80   0 465,8G  0 disk                                      
└─sdf1   8:81   0 465,8G  0 part /mnt/win10_utilities ntfs
```

break

```
[root@desktop-linux fabrizio]# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[cde]
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : 0028b89b
         Family : 0028b89b
     Generation : 00000062
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 137d7329:b874d09c:ecb307ad:bfd6b70a
       Checksum : 1468caa4 correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 3
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCC4M4EYDENC
          State : active
             Id : 00000002
    Usable Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

[Volume0]:
           UUID : 92c1c9bd:d1701a29:94bf5aa6:be8fd1d8
     RAID Level : 5 <-- 5
        Members : 3 <-- 3
          Slots : [UUU] <-- [UUU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 0
     Array Size : 7814047744 (3726.03 GiB 4000.79 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 15261812
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB <-- 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : initialize
      Map State : normal <-- uninitialized
     Checkpoint : 567605 (768)
    Dirty State : clean

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WCC4M5AK581C
          State : active
             Id : 00000003
    Usable Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

  Disk02 Serial : WD-WCC4M5AK5JKY
          State : active
             Id : 00000004
    Usable Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : 0028b89b
         Family : 0028b89b
     Generation : 00000062
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 137d7329:b874d09c:ecb307ad:bfd6b70a
       Checksum : 1468caa4 correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 3
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WCC4M5AK581C
          State : active
             Id : 00000003
    Usable Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

[Volume0]:
           UUID : 92c1c9bd:d1701a29:94bf5aa6:be8fd1d8
     RAID Level : 5 <-- 5
        Members : 3 <-- 3
          Slots : [UUU] <-- [UUU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 1
     Array Size : 7814047744 (3726.03 GiB 4000.79 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 15261812
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB <-- 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : initialize
      Map State : normal <-- uninitialized
     Checkpoint : 567605 (768)
    Dirty State : clean

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCC4M4EYDENC
          State : active
             Id : 00000002
    Usable Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

  Disk02 Serial : WD-WCC4M5AK5JKY
          State : active
             Id : 00000004
    Usable Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
/dev/sde:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.3.00
    Orig Family : 0028b89b
         Family : 0028b89b
     Generation : 00000062
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 137d7329:b874d09c:ecb307ad:bfd6b70a
       Checksum : 1468caa4 correct
    MPB Sectors : 2
          Disks : 3
   RAID Devices : 1

  Disk02 Serial : WD-WCC4M5AK5JKY
          State : active
             Id : 00000004
    Usable Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

[Volume0]:
           UUID : 92c1c9bd:d1701a29:94bf5aa6:be8fd1d8
     RAID Level : 5 <-- 5
        Members : 3 <-- 3
          Slots : [UUU] <-- [UUU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 2
     Array Size : 7814047744 (3726.03 GiB 4000.79 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 15261812
     Chunk Size : 128 KiB <-- 128 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : initialize
      Map State : normal <-- uninitialized
     Checkpoint : 567605 (768)
    Dirty State : clean

  Disk00 Serial : WD-WCC4M4EYDENC
          State : active
             Id : 00000002
    Usable Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)

  Disk01 Serial : WD-WCC4M5AK581C
          State : active
             Id : 00000003
    Usable Size : 3907024136 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
```

mdadm --detail --scan returns an empty string.

Comment: I can confirm this still affects Debian Buster, but mdadm-3.2/.3 no longer build cleanly on that platform, so it might be a bit to debug.

Comment: I finally built mdadm-3.2 and tested it on Debian 10 with kernel 4.19: "mdadm --detail --scan" returns an empty string for me too, even though "mdadm --examine some-disks" still shows my isw_raid_members correctly, so perhaps this is due to a kernel or udev difference instead of mdadm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I'm not sure how it worked on Debian 8, but on Debian 10, Intel RST is handled by dmraid, and automatically assembled a virtual block device at /dev/mapper/isw_<10lettershere>_Volume_0000

dmesg showed these relevant lines:

```
[21120.363597] md/raid:mdX: device sda operational as raid disk 0
[21120.363600] md/raid:mdX: device sdb operational as raid disk 1
[21120.363601] md/raid:mdX: device sdc operational as raid disk 2
[21120.363602] md/raid:mdX: device sdd operational as raid disk 3
[21120.364249] md/raid:mdX: raid level 5 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 0
```

dmsetup listed the device:

```
rsaxvc@localghost:/$ sudo dmsetup ls
isw_bcegjbdfjj_Volume_0000  (254:0)
```

Probing the block device for partitions with partprobe found them:

```
rsaxvc@localghost:/$ sudo partprobe /dev/mapper/isw_<10letters>_Volume_0000
rsaxvc@localghost:/$ ls /dev/mapper/isw_*
  /dev/mapper/isw_<10letters>_Volume_0000  
  /dev/mapper/isw_<10letters>_Volume_0000p1  
  /dev/mapper/isw_<10letters>_Volume_0000p2
```

At this point I was able to mount one of the partitions that another OS had created on the Intel RST volume under Debian 10. These are the relevant versions that came with Debian 10 on my machine:

```
rsaxvc@localghost:~$ dmraid --version
dmraid version:     1.0.0.rc16 (2009.09.16) shared 
dmraid library version: 1.0.0.rc16 (2009.09.16)
device-mapper version:  4.39.0
rsaxvc@localghost:~$ uname -a
Linux localghost 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
rsaxvc@localghost:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```